# Netsuite add create new purchase order button in case form

Tags: button, netsuite

New to netsuite and I'm trying to use the case system like a work order system for our property management company. I want to be able to create a purchase order from the case record and have it automatically linked back.  I've already crested the custom field in purchase order to link the case;however I'm trying to make a create purchase order button on the case form.

I understand I have to make a suitescript and then attach it to the custom action sub tab in the form setup, I need help writing the suitescript file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a button to the Case Record, set a user event on before load for case record.
The user event would be something like this :

```
function BeforeLoadCase(type, form) {
try {
    form.setScript('customscript_create_po');
    form.addButton('custpage_custombutton', 'Create PO', 'CreatePO()');
}
catch (err) {
    nlapiLogExecution('error', 'BeforeLoadCase', err);
}}
```

'**customscript_create_po**' : this is a client script , that opens a new purchase order record on the button click. Its code is as follow :

```
function CreatePO() {
var url = nlapiResolveURL('record', 'purchaseorder', null, 'edit') + '?case_id=' + nlapiGetRecordId();
window.open(url, "New Purchase Order");}
```

Now, on the purchase order deploy a user event(before load), code somewhat like :

```
function BeforeLoadPO(type, form, request) {
if (type == 'create' && request.getParameter('case_id') != null) {
    var caseRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('supportcase', request.getParameter('case_id'));

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script should look like this

```
location.href = nlapiResolveURL('record','purchaseorder',null,'edit') + '?case_id=' + nlapiGetRecordId();
```

Further more you have to handle this query string parameter in before load event of the purchase order and set it in your custom field.

Comment: Hi Saqib, thanks for your help. I've saved this as a .js file, created a suitescript, called the function pobutton, and added a custom action for a create po button in the case form.  I've added the suitescript into the case form under custom code. Issues are, when I edit work order the script automatically happens without clicking the button. 2. The case ID is not showing up in my case field in the purchase order. For further details it's a custom field I created on the purchase order that's connected to the case record. The ID of the field is called custbody1.  Thanks for any other input

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
window.location.href = nlapiResolveURL('record','purchaseorder') + '?record.custbody1=' + nlapiGetRecordId();
```

That code should redirect you to your PO form and then pre-populate the custom field for you.